# Sharepoint React Framework , office ui fabric css not getting applied on components

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, office-ui-fabric-react

This is the current version of office ui fabric  referened in my package :
[image]
I am using sharepoint react framework and have used List component : 
Code Link : https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/List/examples/List.Basic.Example.tsx
site link : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/list

But the css is not getting applied ?
[image]

Is there any specific approach for uploading it

Expected behavior:

[image]

This is very urgent, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you importing SCSS file in your webpart and using it like `<div style={styles.wrapper}> ..... </div>`. Here `styles.wrapper` is referring to your SCSS file imported as `styles` containing `wrapper`.

Comment: I was missing this line in tsx file : import 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/List/examples/List.Basic.Example.scss'; Also you need to reference @import '~office-ui-fabric-react/dist/sass/_References.scss'; this line in your module.scss .By default it points to office ui fabric core.